# Opening and Closing a Drawer in React.js using Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the React Material Web Components(https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/) for my UI library.

I tried to implement the drawer for my interface.

**Drawer,js**

```
export default class DrawerBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        temporary
        open={this.props.opened}
        >
        <DrawerHeader>
          <headline6>Headline 6</headline6>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <DrawerContent>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
          <SimpleListItem graphic="favorite" text="Body 2"/>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
```

**navbar that has the icon that opens the drawer**

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarRow>
          <ToolbarSection alignStart>
            <ToolbarMenuIcon use="menu" onClick={this.props.toggle}/>
            <ToolbarTitle>Syngenta Digital Innovation Lab Web UI Boilerplate</ToolbarTitle>
          </ToolbarSection>
          <ToolbarSection alignEnd>
            <ToolbarIcon use="share" onClick={this.props.login}/>
            <ToolbarIcon use="favorite" onClick={this.props.login}/>
            <ToolbarIcon use="search" onClick={this.props.login}/>
          </ToolbarSection>
        </ToolbarRow>
      </Toolbar>
    )
  }
}
```

**and App.js that uses it**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { drawer: false, login: false }

  drawerToggle = () => { this.setState( { ...this.state, drawer: !this.state.drawer } ) }
  loginToggle = () => { this.setState( { ...this.state, login: !this.state.login } ) }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">

        <Login opened={this.state.login} toggle={this.loginToggle}/>
        <DrawerBar opened={this.state.drawer}/>
        <div className="body">
          <Navbar toggle={this.drawerToggle} login={this.loginToggle}/>
          <Feed/>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

whenever I click the button that opens it, it works fine, but it does NOT close when I click on the background.

I am assuming this is because the `open` parameter for `Drawer` is a prop, not a state.

But I am not sure how I can adjust this issue.

Answer (score -2):

it's not to do with whether you are passing state or props. You are basically missing some props argument and state change here.

First of all, Drawer takes a second prop called `onClose` and you should be passing your `toggle` function here. Reference is here https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/

Furthermore, do make sure you pass `onClick` listener and `onKeydown` listener to your drawer contents and also provide your toggle event so that the drawer closes when click has been made on your drawer (unless this is not the desired effect)

Comment: This has nothing to do with programatically opening or closing the drawer.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
onClick=this.drawerToggle(true)
```

or

```
onClick=this.drawerToggle(this.props.opened)
```

(as the case may be) as attribute on `<Drawer />`

Comment: this.drawerToggle is not a function. Are you lifting state to achieve this programatically? How did you even get a reference to the `<Drawer />` Object, let alone call a non existent method? Where did you come across this information?

Comment: <Drawer /> comes from React Material Web Components as described above. The method drawerToggle is defined in App.js.